# How to add Option group in HTML select?

Tags: html

How can I add option group in HTML select tag?
I want to categories my option list with option group....how can I use it?

Here is an example

```
<select>
<!-- First category option -->
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
<!-- Second catgory option -->
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just an note `<optgroup>` can not be nested per spec

Answer (score 54, accepted):

By using the `optgroup` tag. Here is an example:

```
<select name="browser">

    <optgroup label="Firefox">
      <option value="2.0 or higher">
        Firefox 2.0 or higher
      </option>
      <option value="1.5.x">Firefox 1.5.x</option>
      <option value="1.0.x">Firefox 1.0.x</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Microsoft Internet Explorer">
      <option value="7.0 or higher">
        Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0 or higher
      </option>
      <option value="6.x">Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.x</option>
      <option value="5.x">Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.x</option>
      <option value="4.x">Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.x</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Opera">
      <option value="9.0 or higher">Opera 9.0 or higher</option>
      <option value="8.x">Opera 8.x</option>
      <option value="7.x">Opera 7.x</option>
    </optgroup>

    <option>Safari</option>
    <option>Other</option>

</select>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I think you mean "value" attribute instead of "label" attribute in <option> tag.

Comment: @g.annunziata Not according to Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup) tag in which you should nest your options.

Answer (score 4):

[Optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Linking to w3scools is not a good idea, better to use MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` `option` in  `optgroup` as discuss above.

But I will show how to group `select` in `Angular` in `*ngFor` loop

```
          <select class="form-control">
            <option value=null disabled selected>Select</option>
            <optgroup label="Active">
              <option *ngFor="let type of userInformationTypes" [value]="type.value">{{type.text}}</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Inactive">
              <option *ngFor="let type of inActiveUserInformation" [value]="type.value">{{type.text}}</option> 
            </optgroup>
          </select>
```